# How do you convert RGB lux into a singular value?

Tags: visible-light, electronics

I'm trying to understand the output from an RGBW optical sensor. According to the specification for the sensor this outputs lux. I was hoping someone could explain how the 3 RGB lux values relate to the white lux value.

Some examples of the data I have collected are:

```
Red 11.07, Green 5.37, Blue 2.64, White 6.32
Red 551.08, Green 360.80, Blue 252.00, White 638.55
```

Is it as simple as combining and averaging the RGB to get the white lux reading?

An example sensor would be something like http://www.vishay.com/optical-sensors/list/product-84276/

Many Thanks

Comment: I think this is more an engineering question than a physics one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not simple. The sensor you linked has 4 independent photodiodes, each with its own optical filter, and each gives a different result. In a perfect world, the 3 color sensors would exactly cover the overall spectrum of the white sensor, with no gaps or overlaps. AND the responsivity of each color sensor would be exactly the same as the white sensor for the same wavelength.

If you look at Figure 4 on the data sheet, you will see that this is not remotely true. There is significant overlap between the color sensors (note that the red response is almost 70% in the peak blue region) and the white sensor has significant response in the IR (700 to 900 nm) which is completely absent from the color sensors.

You should read up on the relationship of lux and wavelength. Here http://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae409.cfm is a start. What Vishay has done with this sensor is to use an unspecified white LED as the source, measure the power/wavelength to produce a total lux quantity, then categorize the sensor output in terms of this source.

Answer (score 1):

In the first of your data sets, it does look like the white value is (close to) the average of the RGB values.  In the second one, the white value is significantly greater (average of RGB ~= 388, but W ~= 639).

Looking at the data sheet, the W sensor includes a significant range of infrared in its spectral response (see the graph on page 5) which might explain the greater value.

You could also test the sensor by putting it in front of a computer screen and displaying solid red, green, blue and white and seeing what the results are.